# how to get all open pages of android google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, screen-scraping

could you please help me, I need to detect all the open pages  in google chrome  Android and export to  a file

I used to use devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html with usb debugging, but it is obsolete

Now you should use chrome://inspect/devices, I am using this code in chrome devtools:

```
ars = document.querySelectorAll('div.list.pages')[2].querySelectorAll('div.subrow')
for (i = 0; i < ars.length; ++i) {
  e1 = ars[i].querySelector('div.name').innerText
  e2 = ars[i].querySelector('div.url').innerText
  console.log(e1+';'+e2)
}
```

to get all the pages and names but they leave incomplete.

url showeded: https://windowserver.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-standard-deployment…

the complete url: https://windowserver.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-standard-deployment-parte-4-instalando-licencias-rdcal/

Do you know any alternative to get google chrome pages from android?

Comment: Check the last comment in this thread - https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs/177760

Comment: Check out this thread especially the last comment - https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56635/how-can-i-export-the-list-of-open-chrome-tabs/177760